# invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++

Seems to be something wrong with string slicing  text[i], what's wrong with that ?

Error show up in eclipse

```
invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]  test.cpp    /Standford.Programming  line 17 C/C++ Problem
```

Code

```
string CensorString1(string text, string remove){
    for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++){
        string ch = text[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: did you *want* a 1-char-length `std::string` in that loop? It is unclear whether you wanted a single-char `std::string` or just a single `char`. And maybe pass those parameters by const-ref and give you memory-bus a wee break.

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't be wrong? Do you know what a `char` is and what's the difference to a `char*`? `const` is just a modifier, the compiler tells you that two items have different type. When you try to explain the expected behavior this becomes clear. Try asking with this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
string ch = text[i];
```

`text[i]` is a `char` not a `string`. You are indexing into `text` remember so if `text equals "sometext"` and `i equals 3` - `text[i]` means `e`. Change the above code to:

```
char ch = text[i];
```

Use `str.push_back(ch)` to append. Read about [std::string::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/)

> Appends character c to the end of the string, increasing its length by one.

Comment: @Hellolad - why do you want to convert a `char` to a `string`?

Comment: I would like to use str.append(ch)

Comment: i.g. string str = "abc" ; str.append(str[1]); thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
text[i]
```

returns a char - so you should use:

```
char c = text[i];
```

otherwise the compiler tries to construct a `string` from a `char`, it can only "convert" a `const char *` as string though. Thats the reason for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

From the name of your function, I guess you want to do this ...

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
string CensorString1 ( string text, string const & remove ) {
   for(;;) {
      size_t pos = text.find(remove);
      if ( pos == string::npos ) break;
      text.erase(pos,remove.size());
   }
   return text;
}
```

... or that:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
string CensorString1 ( string text, string const & remove ) {
   size_t pos = text.find(remove);
   if ( pos != string::npos ) text.erase(pos,remove.size());
   return text;
}
```